# How can I use scopes from multiple schemas to constrain my query results?

Tags: elixir, ecto

Suppose I have Ecto schemas `Author` and `Book`. I have "scope" functions for each: `Author.name_ilike(name)` and `Book.bestselling`.

**How can I combine these two functions to run an `INNER JOIN` query for authors with names like "Anna" who have bestselling books?**

I'm picturing SQL like:

```
SELECT *
FROM authors
INNER JOIN books ON books.author_id = authors.id
WHERE authors.name ILIKE "%anna%"
AND books.sales_count > 2000000
```

### Clarification

I've borrowed the term "scope" from Ruby's ActiveRecord; I don't know a term for "Ecto function which defines or narrows a query". For reference, the ActiveRecord way to do this would be `Author.name_like(name).merge(Book.bestselling)`.

Comment: Could you post the contents of those two functions as well? I guess by "scope" you mean like ActiveRecord scopes but still.

Comment: Yes, by "scopes" I mean something like ActiveRecord scopes. Is there a better name for "function which narrows an Ecto query"? My specific schemas and functions are more complicated - I was hoping this example would make the question simpler to answer. Right now I'm trying a `|> join(:inner, ^OtherSchema.some_scope(some_args))` and getting an error: `(ArgumentError) expected join to be a string, atom or {string, atom}, got: `#Ecto.Query...`

Comment: `|> join(:inner, [], subquery(OtherSchema.some_scope(some_args)))`? (You'll probably want to add the `on` condition as well.)

Comment: (I don't think my previous comment will produce the same query. I'll delete it once you confirm.)

Comment: Looks like joining arbitrary queries would work in Ecto 2.1: https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/commit/41cadec6c897ddc8270b0cb49df57bb9ea7c4d8f. I'm unable to get it working with my app due to some dependency conflicts but you might want to try 2.1.0-rc4 or later.

Comment: @Dogbert Nice find! That does look like what I want, but I also have a dependency conflict with trying it on my code. Hopefully that will all get worked out soon.

Comment: There's also dynamic/1 introduced in one of the latest releases, that might help with what you're trying to do https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#dynamic-expressions